# Reading package lists... Error! GPG error and problem with Mergelist

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm having problems upgrading packages in my Ubuntu 14.04. I retried several time but the problem persists and the message says I should report to developers

The following is my error

```
Reading package lists... Error!
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your apt-get cache:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Create a new list of apt-get packages

```
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.orig
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
```

Update your source lists

```
sudo apt-get update
```